# Detach an Object from a Realm?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Lets say I have the following scenario...

`ViewController1` loads a `Person` object from a Realm on the main thread and passes it to `ViewController2`. User interaction in `ViewController2` causes the same `Person` object to change, but I only want to persist the changes once the User has pressed "Save".

Currently, when changing the passed `Person` object in `ViewController2` a runtime error is thrown saying changes to an object need to be made in a Write block. This makes sense, but in this scenario I don't actually want to persist the changes right away.

- Is there a way to detach an Object from a Realm to avoid these
  checks?
- If there isn't, what would be a suggested work around? (Copying the Object to a new instance? Tracking the changes to the Object separately and applying them later? Both seem pretty messy.)

Comment: Maybe related https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1202

Comment: Look here: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/ in "Updating objects" section,  if you have a primary key you can use `Realm().add(_:update:)`. So it seems you have re-create the object and when you want to save it do the write transaction and do the update.

Comment: Thanks Ixx, that's the same problem I am experiencing. My object is rather large (lots of fields) and I don't want to have to copy it all to a new object every time. :(

Comment: Understandable... I'm also interested in the answers :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Right now, you can make a 'standalone' copy of your object, via `Object(value: existingObject)` -- that'll probably be the simplest solution for now, until Realm adds something like nested transactions that will make `undo`ing an arbitrary number of changes easier.

Comment: Is this a way in Swift to init a new object from existing one? Is there a similar way in OC?

Comment: Based on the current tests, this detaches the object, but does not detach the related objects - trying to modify a related object from a to-many relation still shows "Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction"

Comment: Please note that the object is a shallow copy of the original

Answer (score 0):

Realm has added a `freeze()` function for Realm Objects on RealmSwift 5.+ versions.

Imagine we have a Realm object `Edible` with a property name. Previously you weed need to hold a `ThreadSafeReference` to the object, get a realm on the other thread and unwrap the reference. Meh.

If you didn't, it would crash:

```
// Code running on main thread
let edible = realm.objects(Edible.self)[0]
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background) {
   let name = edible.name // Realm accessed from incorrect thread error
}
```

How to do detach an object in `RealmSwift 5.+`:

```
let edible = realm.objects(Edible.self)[0].freeze()
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background) {
    let name = edible.name // No longer crashes
}
```

Keep in mind as of Jan 11 2021, the `freeze()` function can create a lot of unknown weird errors affecting the users, as mentioned repeatedly in the issues for the new Realm version. For now, stay away from it. Use deep copying.

Comment: How to do deep copying?